# Filling in date values from an initial to terminal date in R within a data frame

Tags: r

I am currently trying to find a solution to inserting rows/dates between a baseline date and whatever dates appear next to my data. The data looks like the following:

```
> Data
A     B     Time 
11    22    2012-01-01
11    25    2012-01-04
11    33    2012-01-07
11    37    2012-01-22
```

I would like to have 2012-01-01 as my base time, and create a data table like the following:

```
A     B     Time 
11    22    2012-01-01
11    25    2012-01-01
11    25    2012-01-02
11    25    2012-01-03
11    25    2012-01-04
11    25    2012-01-01
11    25    2012-01-02
11    25    2012-01-03
11    25    2012-01-04
11    33    2012-01-01
11    33    2012-01-02
11    33    2012-01-03
11    33    2012-01-04
11    33    2012-01-05
11    33    2012-01-06
11    33    2012-01-07
11    37    2012-01-01
11    37    2012-01-02
       .....
11    37    2012-01-21
11    37    2012-01-22
```

Basically, I am trying to start each entry of B at the time 2012-01-01 and then create consecutive time intervals down until I hit the respective time entry of B.

The Time variable I have is recognized as "Date" when I do the command:

```
class(Data$Time)
> "Date"
```

Now, here is my code so far:

```
starttime <- "2012-01-01"
newData<- Data[1,]
for(i in 1:nrow(Data)){
if (Data[i+1,3] > starttime) 
{newData <- rbind(newData, Data[i+1,3]+1  }
}
```

However, I cannot think of a simpler way to implement this. Does anyone know of any simple ways of filling in the time data for each value of column B to have it start from an initial date? Thank you!

Comment: What's going on with the years in these dates?

Comment: "2012-01-02" represents January 2nd, 2012.

Comment: And "2013-01-07" followed by "2012-01-22"?

Comment: made a mistake, should be all 2012, just fixed it!

Comment: I think you have too many `B == 25` in your desired out put

Answer (score 1):

I would just do it like this:

```
diffs <- mydf$Time - mydf$Time[1] + 1
mydf <- mydf[rep(rownames(mydf), diffs), ]
mydf$Time <- mydf$Time[1] + (sequence(diffs) - 1)
```

As @David notes, if you need to start from a different date you can replace `mydf$Time[1]` with the date you want to start with (for example, `as.Date("2012-01-01")`).

Comment: This is essentially the same as David's answer, just with a trick to expand the first two columns....

Comment: I deleted mine, as it seems that your is better, but I still think you should replace `mydf$Time[1]` with `as.Date("2012-01-01")`